# Passar descriptor por parâmetro para outro descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, descriptors

Imaginemos que em uma classe eu tenha duas propriedade do tipo descriptor. O primeiro deles garante que a propriedade em questão são seja negativa o segundo deve garantir que a propriedade associada à ele não será maior do que a propriedade anterior.

Para exemplificar:

```
class AnyClass:

    prop1 = NaoMenorQueZero()
    prop2 = NaoMenorQue(#prop1)

    def __init__(self, prop1, prop2):
        self.prop1 = prop1
        self.prop2 = prop2
```

Ou seja, `prop2` tem que ser menor que `prop1`. E na intenção de ter um descritor que possa ser usado para outras situações pessei em receber o valor a ser comparado por parâmetro (`NaoMenorQue(#prop1)`). Lá no corpo do descriptor, na hora que é feita uma atribuição (`prop2 = 10`), no método `__set__` é feita a comparação para ver se `value` é menor que o valor passado na hora da inicialização:

```
def __init__(self, dt):
    self.__dt = dt

def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    return instance.__dict__[self.__name]

def __set__(self, instance, value):
    if value <= self.__dt:
        instance.__dict__[self.__name] = value
    else:
        raise ValueError()

def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
    self.__name = name
```

O problema dessa lógica é que o atributo `self.__dt` está recebendo um objeto do tipo `NaoMenorQueZero`, ou seja, o descriptor propriamente dito e não apenas o seu valor. E na hora da comparação o `__set__` está fazendo `int <= NaoMenorQuezero` ao invés de `int <= int`.
Para solucionar isso eu poderia sobrecarregar os operadores <,>,== e !=
no descriptor `NaoMenorQueZero` mas isso seria um trabalho arduo pois `NaoMenorQue` pode ser usado em várias ocasiões e eu teria a obrigação de sobrecarregar os operadores de todos os descroptors que fossem ser passados como parâmetro à ele.

Alguma outra solução?

Comment: Tente criar um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ficaria mais fácil p tentar ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A instância de um descriptor é uma propriedade da classe do objeto que usa os descriptors. Isso significa que se você está criando um descriptor para armazenar um valor individual  em cada instância, esse valor tem que ser guardado na instância a qual o descriptor está associado - por isso que os métodos de descriptor `__get__` , `__set__` e `__del__` recebem o parâmetro "instance".

(Você pode ter um outro objeto "global" para os seus descriptord que guarde os dados separados das instâncias - mas não vale a pena, porque você teria que criar toda uma lógica a parte para apagar os dados referentes a instâncias que não existem mais).

Em geral, como está no seu próprio código, esses valores são guardados na própria instância - ou com acesso direto ao atributo, com o operador `.`, ou pode ser usando  o `__dict__` da instância, como você faz.

mas então, o valor armazenado pelo primeiro descriptor - esse que você quer verificar - ele é recuperado da instância, não do descriptor. Você pode ou "hardcodar" o acesso àquele valor, ou, melhor, simplesmente usar o próprio descriptor para acessar o valor - o que é melhor.

Uma outra coisa legal que você pod usar, já que está escrevendo seus descriptors, é implementar método  `__set_name__`, que existe do Python 3.6 em diante, e é chamado quando a classe que definiu o descriptor é criada, com o nome que ele vai ter. Com isso, você pode armazenar internamente o nome do descriptor, e usar uma variante desse nome (por exemplo, com um prefixo), para armazenar os valores relacionados no `__dict__` da instância.

Antes de eu colocar um exemplo concreto, uma última dica: não use `__` como prefixo de nomes de variáveis em Python  para achar que são "variáveis privadas". Esse prefixo faz name mangling - é algo que não foi feito para indicar que uma variável é privada - é pra uma classe poder ter variáveis independentes de outras classes que herdem dela mesma. Python não tem variáveis privadas - tem a **convenção** de que nomes iniciados  com `_` (um único underline) são privados - e isso sinaliza para os usuários das suas classes não acessarem esses nomes diretamente.

```
def MyDescriptorBase:
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None: 
            return self
        return instance.__dict__["_" + self.name]


def NonNegative(MyDescriptorBase):

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("...")
        instance.__dict__["_" + self.name] = value


def NoLessThanDescriptor(MyDescriptorBase):
    def __init__(self, other_desc):
        self.other_desc = other_desc

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        # Para recuperar o valor que o outro descriptor tem:
        instance_value = self.other_desc.__get__(instance, owner)
        if value < instance_value:
            raise ValueError("...")


# E então, você pode referenciar um descriptor 
# como parâmetro de outro no corpo de uma classe,
# respeitando a ordem (só é possível referenciar
# um descriptor que já foi definido)

class Exemplo:

     positivo = NonNegative()
     maior_numero = NoLessThanDescriptor(positivo)
     ...
```

O que responde a sua pergunta é a forma como se recupera o valor do outro descriptor: simplesemente se faz a chamada explícita ao método `__get__` dele, passando os parâmetros de instance e owner.

(Claro que você não precisa ter uma classe base para os descriptors, mas nesse exemplo os métodos `__get__` e `__set_name__` seriam os mesmos - não há necessidade de repetir código)

Mas então - talvez você prefira essa outra abordagem, ao mesmo tempo mais genérica e mais simples: em vez de passar um outro descriptor que será a base de comparação, passe simplesmente o nome de um atributo, como string mesmo. Dessa forma, você pode usar o builtin `getattr` do Python, e recuperar o valor que está na instância para o outro atributo, que não precisa ser um descriptor - pode ser qualquer tipo de atributo:

```
def NoLessThanAttribute(MyDescriptorBase):

    def __init__(self, other_attr: str):
        self.other_attr = other_attr

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance_value = getattr(instance, self.other_attr)
        if value < instance_value:
            raise ValueError("...")
```

Comment: Parabéns John! Como sempre matando a pau nesses temas mais complexos.